# How to get Protected Friend proprty from multilevel inherited class using reflection?

Tags: c#, vb.net, reflection, properties

I have class structure somewhat like this,

```
 public class a
       Protected Friend Property ID() As Integer
        Get
            Return _Id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
            _Id = Value
        End Set
    End Property 
    //some other properties and methods
 End class


 public class b 
       Inherits a
        //some properties and methods
 End Class


 public class c 
       Inherits b
        //some properties and methods
 End Class

 public class d 
       Inherits c
        //some properties and methods

       Dim obj as D = new D();
       Dim data = obj.GetType().GetProperties(/*I have tried all binding flags here*/) 

 End Class
```

I want to access the `ID` property from `class a` from the object of `Class D`. Till now I googled and found lots of answer's from stack but any of those answers didn't give me what I want.

I get that property when I use code like,

```
 'obj.GetType().BaseType.BaseType.BaseType.GetProperties()'
```

But the use of the repetitive `BaseType` property doesn't look good and also it might cause problem if I add More inheritance in between in future. SO is there any way to avoid that and get what I want. If any confusion feel free to comment.

P.S- I have already tried lot of stack answers regarding this but not able to get what I want. If you know the C# way then also please suggest I will convert it to the VB.

Comment: Downvoter please care to mention the reason ?

Comment: You have directly access to you EntityID propertie in d class. or I don't understand your question. you can access to your EntityID in method or property

Comment: That's a confusing mix of C# and VB in your sample code (E.g. it looks like VB but it has C# style comments and a stray `;` (also, 'twould be better if the code at the bottom was inside a valid block, e.g. a `Sub` or `Function`)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever sorry for that Basically I am c# coder recently started on VB so old habits came out when typing in here. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a `Sub` in `d`:

```
Sub DoStuff()
    Dim obj As d = New d()
    Dim data = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
End Sub
```

When I step over the `data` line, `data` gets set to an array containing a single property - the `EntityID` property from the `a` class.

Or, if we don't want to search that array, we can go straight to that property:

```
Dim eid = obj.GetType().GetProperty("EntityID", _
                                    BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't tried all binding flags.

```
myD.GetType().GetProperties(
              BindingFlags.NonPublic or _
              BindingFlags.Instance)
```

Should work. I've made a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ym0khU

Or directly:

```
myD.GetType().GetProperty("EntityID", 
              BindingFlags.NonPublic or _
              BindingFlags.Instance)
```

**Update**: As @Damien_The_Unbeliever pointed out, `FlattenHierarchy` is not necessary for instance properties

Comment: `FlattenHierarchy` isn't required here. It only relates to statics (or `Shared` in VB parlance)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are totally right, plus, now that I read it, your answer was already correct. Let me update and upvote your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can directly access to your property

```
  Module Module1

        Sub Main()
            Dim test As d = New d()
            test.EntityID = 52
            Dim t As Integer = test.EntityID
            Dim t1 As Integer = test.GetEntityID

        End Sub


        Public Class a
            Dim _entityId As Integer
            Protected Friend Property EntityID() As Integer
                Get
                    Return _entityId
                End Get
                Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
                    _entityId = Value
                End Set
            End Property

        End Class


        Public Class b
            Inherits a

        End Class


        Public Class c
            Inherits b

        End Class

        Public Class d
            Inherits c


            Public Function GetEntityID() As Integer

                Dim test As Integer = Me.EntityID
                Return test
            End Function

        End Class

    End Module
```

Comment: Since the question is tagged [tag:reflection] and the title ends with "using reflection", I think they're looking for a reflection-based answer here.

Comment: Sorry now I understand

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your ideas

I try and add GetPropertyName()

It's work fine

```
        Sub DoStuff()
            Dim obj As d = New d()
            Dim data As PropertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(GetPropertyName(Function() obj.EntityID), BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            Dim x = data.GetValue(obj, Nothing)
        End Sub
        Public Function GetPropertyName(Of T)(prop As Expression(Of Func(Of T))) As String
            Dim expression = GetMemberInfo(prop)
            Return expression.Member.Name
        End Function
        Private Function GetMemberInfo(method As Expression) As MemberExpression
            Dim lambda As LambdaExpression = TryCast(method, LambdaExpression)
            If lambda Is Nothing Then
                Throw New ArgumentNullException("method")
            End If

            Dim memberExpr As MemberExpression = Nothing

            If lambda.Body.NodeType = ExpressionType.Convert Then
                memberExpr = TryCast(DirectCast(lambda.Body, UnaryExpression).Operand, MemberExpression)
            ElseIf lambda.Body.NodeType = ExpressionType.MemberAccess Then
                memberExpr = TryCast(lambda.Body, MemberExpression)
            End If

            If memberExpr Is Nothing Then
                Throw New ArgumentException("method")
            End If

            Return memberExpr
        End Function
```